# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization basis for Continuous functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to find an orthogonal basis of

1. the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $v_1=(1,1,0,0),v_2=(1,1,1,0) \,and, v_3=(1,1,1,1)$ with respect to the (standard) inner product $<(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)>=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4$.
2. the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $V_1=(1,1,0,0),v_2=(1,1,1,0) \,and, v_3=(1,1,1,1)$ with respect to the inner product $<(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)>=x_1y_1+2x_2y_2+x_3y_3+2x_4y_4$.
3. the subspaces of $W_1$, where $W_1$ is the subspace of C(0,1); spanned by the functions $\{e^x,xe^x,x^2e^x\}$ with the inner product
   $<f,g>=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx$

$\textbf{Orthogonal basis for Part a}$
\begin{cases}
\overrightarrow{y_1}=v_1=(1,1,0,0) \\
\overrightarrow{y_2}=v_2-P_{\overrightarrow{y_1}} v_2=v_2-\overrightarrow{y_1}\frac{<\overrightarrow{y_1},v_2>}{<\overrightarrow{y_1},\overrightarrow{y_1}>}=(1,1,1,0)-(1,1,0,0)\frac{2}{2}=(0,0,1,0) \\
\overrightarrow{y_3}=v_3-P_{\overrightarrow{y_1}}v_3-P_{\overrightarrow{y_2}}v_3=(1,1,1,1)-(1,1,0,0)\frac{2}{2}-(0,0,1,0)\frac{1}{1}=(0,0,0,1) \\
\end{cases}

Hence the orthogonal basis is $\{(1,1,0,0);(0,0,1,0);(0,0,0,1)\}$.

$\textbf{Orthogonal basis for Part b}$
\begin{cases}
\overrightarrow{y_1}=v_1=(1,1,0,0) \\
\overrightarrow{y_2}=v_2-P_{\overrightarrow{y_1}} v_2=v_2-\overrightarrow{y_1}\frac{<\overrightarrow{y_1},v_2>}{<\overrightarrow{y_1},\overrightarrow{y_1}>}=(1,1,1,0)-(1,1,0,0)\frac{3}{3}=(0,0,1,0) \\
\overrightarrow{y_3}=v_3-P_{\overrightarrow{y_1}}v_3-P_{\overrightarrow{y_2}}v_3=(1,1,1,1)-(1,1,0,0)\frac{3}{3}-(0,0,1,0)\frac{1}{1}=(0,0,0,1) \\
\end{cases}
]

Hence the orthogonal basis is $\{(1,1,0,0);(0,0,1,0);(0,0,0,1)\}$.

$\textbf{Orthogonal basis for Part c}$
\begin{cases}
\overrightarrow{y_1}=v_1 \\
\overrightarrow{y_2}=v_2-P_{\overrightarrow{y_1}} v_2=v_2-\overrightarrow{y_1}\frac{<\overrightarrow{y_1},v_2>}{<\overrightarrow{y_1},\overrightarrow{y_1}>} \\
\overrightarrow{y_3}=v_3-P_{\overrightarrow{y_1}}v_3-P_{\overrightarrow{y_2}}v_3\\
\end{cases}

How would I do the process for this one?

Comment: You need to evaluate all the terms in the expression for $y_2$. Presumably $v_2$ and $y_1$ are easy -- they're functions you already have written down. Can you evaluate $\langle y_1, v_2\rangle$? You'll need to actually compute an integral to do so.

Comment: But what do I call $v_1$ and so on?

Comment: $v_1$ is the function $x \mapsto e^x$; $v_2$ is the function $x \mapsto xe^x$, etc.

Comment: So just to clarify I name f(x)=x and g(x) whichever element in the basis of $W_1$?

Comment: No. First, $y_1$ is just $v_1$ which is $x \mapsto e^x$. So to find $y_2$, you need to compute, for starters, $\langle y_1, y_1 \rangle$. The definition of the inner product that's given says that this is $\int_0^1 y_1(x) y_1(x) ~dx = \int_0^1 e^x e^x ~dx = \int_0^1 e^{2x}~dx$. I'll let you go ahead and evaluate that.

Comment: So that integral is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(e-1)$

Comment: Good. Now compute $<y_1, v_1>$, and you'll have the numerator of the fraction. Their quotient is a number, which you'll multiply by the function $y_1$, and subtract the result from the function $v_2$, to get a new function, which you'll call $y_2$. Repeat the process to find $y_3$, etc.

Comment: Ok. So to contunie on my own can you explicit write what $v_1$ would be? Also how many $y_n$ will we have?

Comment: I wrote down $v_1$ three comments ago. Will I write down $v_2$? No. "How many $y_n$ will we have"?", you ask. Well, in each of the previous problems, how many vectors did you write down in your answer, compared to the number of vectors given to you at the start of the problem? Spoiler: you'll have $y_1, y_2,$ and $y_3$. Perhaps my "etc." confused you -- I should have omitted it.

Comment: That makes sense. Yes please write down $v_2$

Comment: Nope. YOU write down $v_2$. This feels like a HW problem, and I've done enough.

Comment: Would it be $x^2$ map to $e^x$ and so on?

Comment: Nope. I think it's time for you to talk to the prof/ta/whatever.